# how to use back key to home application page

Tags: android

we used back key by calling

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

but,we used 4 classes in our application.if we gives back button,its  working well and returning to application home page.but wen we go next time  its in same class.(we used above back key coding in 3 rd class,its remains same page).

is there  any alternative method.if anybody knows pls reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

`moveTaskToBack()` only moves the Activity to the back of the activity stack, it doesn't actually close the Activity. What you want is `finish()`, which will close the Activity and Android will automatically take you back to the previous Activity in the stack.

For more information, see the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask

Answer (score 0):

use this...

[onBackPressed not close Current Activity In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250573/onbackpressed-not-close-current-activity-in-android/13250612#13250612)