# onBackPressed not close Current Activity In Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I created an app for playing videos. It works fine but the problem is - when I  press the back button on the device the Activity is not closing. The video is playing in the Background. I am using `onBackpressed()`. How to close the current activity?

Comment: can you post your onBackPressed method?

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();   
          finish();
    }

Comment: did you call `super.onBackpressed()`???

Comment: also stop your player `if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
    mPlayer.stop();`  on  `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Are you loading a flash video in webview ?

Comment: i play the i frame embedded videos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put this code....

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: super.onBackPressed() calls finish() anyway, so you only need one or the other.

Comment: I tried this But not working .the sound is audiable .I heard the video Sound

Comment: may be this link will help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview

Comment: given code is working perfectly in my application..so, use this for close ordinary activity on back button pressed.

Comment: means you want to change the value of a variable ?

Comment: if you change the value in second activity then it is obvious changed....dear..because it is declared as static...but if you not changed your value in second activity then it is remains the same as first activity value..

Comment: yes..take a new variable and assign the static variable value to it when going to next activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19172/discussion-between-user1597094-and-mehul1000)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

//close you app or do what ever you want 
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have two way for this 
**First :**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
    {
        super.finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Second**

```
 @Override public void onBackPressed()
 {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onBackPressed();
   finish(); 
 }
```

Comment: ya if you don't then it will remove only current not all.

Comment: then you should put some more explanation, for both the line so the newer user not get confuse, and off-course not for POINTS; Technicality always welcome.

Comment: Sorry . I will care next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well try this

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.YourWebView);
    webview.stopLoading();
    webview.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Similar here: [android WebView stop Flash plugin onPause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761873/android-webview-stop-flash-plugin-onpause/) and [Embedded IFRAME video keeps playing in background after exiting fullscreen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159144/embedded-iframe-video-keeps-playing-in-background-after-exiting-fullscreen-in-an)

This one would also help if the above doesnt work:
[How to stop youtube video playing in Android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview)

This link basically explains a thread bug in Android webview which was asked here: [WebView threads never stop (WebViewCoreThread, CookieSyncManager, http[0-3])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040963/webview-threads-never-stop-webviewcorethread-cookiesyncmanager-http0-3) - using reflection to access onPause and onResume methods to kill your running threads

Answer (score 0):

You have a different problem, you should not add a workaround to solve this.
Something is catching your onBackPressed - Or your onBackPressed is catched by something, that's why its not working.